# How to build animated headers like this GIF in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In iOS, I wrote a somewhat complex custom UIViewController that handles transitioning between unique child controllers; most notably, a special header view at the top of each one. I'm still trying to really wrap my head around end to end architecture in Flutter, and would like some suggestions on how to accomplish this. There are two types of headers - Arc and Profile, and each one goes from an expanded to a collapsed state as the user scrolls. Additionally, navigation between any combination of type and state can have a transition defined.

[image]

Here is how it looks when used in a TabBar for example. Transitions are handled gracefully wether nested in Tab/NavigationControllers or not.

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This is really cool, but I'm not sure what you are asking for...

Comment: @RémiRousselet I've already successfully built it in Swift. As far as Flutter goes, I'm still taking baby steps with styling ListView items. It seems like app architecture in Flutter is very different from iOS, so I don't think I can simply port over 1:1. There are a lot of tutorials about making basic UI, but I haven't found much about architecture, or how to structure more complex screens like this.

Comment: @boformer Just any sort of guidance on how to structure something like this. There are lots of tutorials on basic screen layouts, but I'm not sure where to even begin with an interactive transition animation between different screens like this. In Swift, I had quite a lot of trouble, and what I did won't translate over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I threw together, I hope it helps (click for video):

[image: Video]

Note:

- It would be better to reduce the amount of animation controllers, ideally to a single controller that controls both the header extent and the arc curvature
- There is no animation for the content below the header, but I'm sure you could add that as well.

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Anim playground',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: AnimatedPageTest(),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedPageTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedPageTestState createState() => _AnimatedPageTestState();
}

class _AnimatedPageTestState extends State<AnimatedPageTest> {
  bool _arc = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: AnimatedPage(
        appearance: _arc ? HeaderAppearance.arc : HeaderAppearance.profile,
        backgroundImage: _arc ? 'assets/earth.jpg' : 'assets/moon.jpg',
        children: List.generate(30, (index) => ListTile(title: Text('index'),)),
      ),),
      persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Switch'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _arc = !_arc;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


enum HeaderAppearance { arc, profile }

double _getTargetMaxExtent(HeaderAppearance appearance) {
  if (appearance == HeaderAppearance.arc) {
    return 150.0;
  } else {
    return 75.0;
  }
}

double _getTargetArcAnimationValue(HeaderAppearance appearance) {
  if (appearance == HeaderAppearance.arc) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

class AnimatedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimatedPage({Key key, this.appearance, this.backgroundImage, this.children}) : super(key: key);

  final HeaderAppearance appearance;
  final String backgroundImage;
  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  _AnimatedPageState createState() => _AnimatedPageState();
}

class _AnimatedPageState extends State<AnimatedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _maxExtentAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _maxExtentAnimation = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this, value: _getTargetMaxExtent(widget.appearance));
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedPage oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.appearance != oldWidget.appearance) {
      _maxExtentAnimation.animateTo(
        _getTargetMaxExtent(widget.appearance),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _maxExtentAnimation.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _maxExtentAnimation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: AnimatedHeaderDelegate(
                appearance: widget.appearance,
                backgroundImage: widget.backgroundImage,
                minExtent: 50.0,
                maxExtent: _maxExtentAnimation.value,
              ),
            ),
            child,
          ],
        );
      },
      child: SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(widget.children)),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  AnimatedHeaderDelegate({this.appearance, this.backgroundImage, this.minExtent, this.maxExtent});

  final HeaderAppearance appearance;

  final String backgroundImage;

  @override
  final double minExtent;
  @override
  final double maxExtent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final shrinkRelative = shrinkOffset / (maxExtent - minExtent);
    return AnimatedHeader(
      appearance: appearance,
      backgroundImage: backgroundImage,
      curvatureMultiplier: 1.0 - shrinkRelative,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(AnimatedHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return appearance != oldDelegate.appearance ||
        minExtent != oldDelegate.minExtent ||
        maxExtent != oldDelegate.maxExtent;
  }
}

class AnimatedHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimatedHeader({Key key, this.appearance, this.backgroundImage, this.curvatureMultiplier}) : super(key: key);

  final HeaderAppearance appearance;

  final String backgroundImage;

  final double curvatureMultiplier;

  @override
  _AnimatedHeaderState createState() => _AnimatedHeaderState();
}

class _AnimatedHeaderState extends State<AnimatedHeader> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _arcAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _arcAnimation = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      value: _getTargetArcAnimationValue(widget.appearance),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedHeader oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.appearance != oldWidget.appearance) {
      _arcAnimation.animateTo(_getTargetArcAnimationValue(widget.appearance));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: CurvedAnimation(parent: _arcAnimation, curve: Curves.linear),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return ClipPath(
          clipper: ArcClipper(
            curvature: _arcAnimation.value * widget.curvatureMultiplier,
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
            child: Container(
              key: ValueKey(widget.backgroundImage),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(widget.backgroundImage),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'TITLE',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArcClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  ArcClipper({this.curvature});

  final double curvature;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    if (curvature == 0.0) {
      return Path()..addRect(Offset.zero & size);
    } else {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(0.0, 0.0)
        ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
        ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height - size.height * 0.4 * curvature, 0.0, size.height)
        ..close();
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(ArcClipper oldClipper) {
    return curvature != oldClipper.curvature;
  }
}
```

Comment: Before I accept this, how do I send you extra karma?

Comment: Good luck with your project ;)